# Get the top left index of an OffsetArray

Tags: julia, offset

I have a following `OffsetArray`:

```
julia> off = OffsetArray(rand(5, 5), -3, -3)
5×5 OffsetArray(::Matrix{Float64}, -2:2, -2:2) with eltype Float64 with indices -2:2×-2:2:
 0.515173  0.861326   0.349478  0.970478  0.255713
 0.862617  0.47006    0.707166  0.938883  0.331716
 0.512007  0.0325946  0.553909  0.569638  0.510056
 0.941383  0.351381   0.35792   0.482246  0.439157
 0.887686  0.413278   0.527105  0.782516  0.976842
```

I would like to extract programmatically the index of the top left element, in this case that would be `(-2, -2)`.

Right now I'm doing this

```
topleft = off |> axes |> CartesianIndices |> first |> ind -> ind.I
```

It looks like an overkill to me, but I couldn't find any other options.

Is there a more direct approach?

Comment: You can shorted what you've written to `CartesianIndices(off)[1].I`, or `off |> CartesianIndices |> first |> Tuple` if you prefer. No need for `axes`, no need to define your own function to convert to a tuple.

Comment: @mcabbott that's a good addittion, thank you. I'm kinda new to julia, so some overengineering happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally use `firstindex`:

```
julia> firstindex(off, 1)
-2
```

where the second argument is a dimension you want to get the first index of.

To get a `(-2, -2)` tuple you can write e.g.:

```
julia> firstindex.(Ref(off), (1, 2))
(-2, -2)
```

Comment: Never seen this usage of `Ref`, thanks for the useful answer

Comment: `Ref` is a standard way of protecting a collection from being broadcasted over, see the comment on broadcasting and example in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Core.Ref.